# What is the purpose and meaning of these machine learning output files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I managed to successfully run this machine learning tutorial (my first one). It does classification using convolutional neural network.

https://github.com/bhimmetoglu/time-series-medicine/blob/master/HAR/HAR-CNN.ipynb

After this machine learning python script using tensor-flow is done, some files are produced in the folder `checkpoints-cnn`.

```
- checkpoint
- har.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
- har.ckpt.index
- har.ckpt.meta
```

What is the purpose and meaning of these machine learning output files? How can I use them to classify real-life data?

I am using python v3.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your estimator, e.g. by running

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(..., model_dir='checkpoints-cnn')
```

tensorflow will try to load the model from the checkpoint, provided the checkpoint is compatible with the definition provided to the estimator intializer.

You can then continue to either train it further, or use it to estimate/classify real-life data.

As for the contents, the .meta file contains the topology of the network, its graph. The .data-[numbers] file contains the weights values, and other variable data. The .index file keeps track of the current checkpoint, I'm not sure exactly what it contains.

Answer (score 2):

Checkpoints are the states of the model while learning. It contains weights and parameters. Each checkpoint can be used for prediction or you can use checkpoint for further learning of the model.